# Like button not showing in Safari iOS on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, facebook-like

I have created a website that has social networking 'likes' etc and have included a Facebook Like button using the js version of the code.

It all works fine on PC in IE/Chrome/Safari but the Like button does not show when the website is accessed using Safari on an iPhone.  The code in the page is as follows:

```
 (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }
 (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

inside a `<script>` tag within `<body>` and:

```
id="FacebookLike" class="fb-like" data-href="www.tri-rn.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="trebuchet ms"
```

inside a `<div>` tag.

Is there something else I need to add to my code to enable Safari iOS to be able to display the Like button?

The website this is used on is http://www.tri-rn.com

Any help will be gratefully received and used!

Comment: I am running into the same issue.  I am getting an error message in the console about a quota exceeded error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have private browsing turned on in the iPhone settings.

Comment: +1 I am seeing the like button just fine in safari on iphone 4 (don't see the google button though)